# Script DB to google sql cloud

Tags: google-apps-script

Is there any possible way to migrate my google appsscript's script db database to Google Sql Cloud .
Any api and any script which will be helpful to transfer my data directly from script DB to google sql cloud database tables......

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to write such script. First, because it highly depends on the structure of your objects stored in ScriptDb and the tables and columns on your cloud-sql.

Anyway, it should be fairly easy. Just loop through your ScriptDb creating the INSERT clauses to cloud-sql, then issue them. It should be no more than 30 lines of code.

If you have many objects stored (e.g. >500). You should paginate the ScriptDb resuls and run your script multiple times to do the job, i.e. splitting the task and working in batches, to avoid hitting the max execution time quota. Also, you should use preparedStatements and addBatch on cloud-sql. Again, all interfaces are built into to Apps Script, this should be easy.